# What is the average temperature of mass in the universe?

Tags: cosmology, temperature, universe, cosmic-microwave-background

That is, ignoring speculative concepts like Dark Matter and just summing across stars and gas clouds etc

Comment: 2.73 Kelvin a pretty good approximation for the current average temperature.

Comment: Instead of mass, you probably should write *baryonic matter*.

Comment: Can you usefully average out stellar cores at $10^7$K and gas clouds at $10$K? Well, obviously it can be done, but has the final figure any meaning? Wouldn't it be more useful to break it down to %age in stars at about xxx K, %age in gas clouds at about yyy K etc?

Comment: @Paul The average temperature is way higher than 2K7

Comment: @JohnRennie Maybe, but another way of asking the question would be to ask "what is the average speed of matter in the universe". And don't give me "Zero" or I will start talking RMS values

Comment: Can you extrapolate from CMB? Consider this is when matter came to be(if I am correct in that assumption).  Follow the laws of thermodynamics and rate of expansion.

Comment: I am also assuming the temperature of "the vacuum of space" and matter(Hydrogen formation) are equal.

Comment: [What's the avarage temperature of the Universe?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59831/whats-the-avarage-temperature-of-the-universe)

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat odd question since average is a somewhat vague term.  Are you referring to temperature averaged by total mass? Or average temperature by volume?

As mentioned in the comment above, the most important "Universal temperature" is the temperature of the [Cosmic Microwave Background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) which is basically the light that was released when the universe cooled enough for electrons to be captured into atoms.  At this point the universe became transparent the first time.  As the universe expanded, the energy density dropped and the photons were stretched until they've moved into the microwave spectrum.  This temperature corresponds to 2.73 K.

However, photons aren't massive, so they don't really fit as matter.  Another important Universal temperature is the [Cosmic Neutrino background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_neutrino_background).  Along with the photons, neutrinos are everywhere throughout space.  They are slightly cooler than photons because they could not couple with the energy produced during the electron-positron annihilation epoch.  The CNB temperature is 1.95K.

These are probably the two most important universal temperature measurements we have.

Comment: Not relevant to the question. Neither photons or neutrinos contribute significant mass to the universe. Almost all baryonic matter is hotter than either.